# update_attributes isn't saving to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, update-attributes

The correct custom params are being displayed in my debug function after the form is submitted but the default params are displayed when I enter console.

**Controller**

```
def update
    current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Your settings have been saved!"
    render new_status_update_path
end
```

**Model**

```
attr_accessible :deficit_pct,
              :target_bf_pct,
              :activity_factor
```

*Notes:*

- The closest question I could find to this on SO is a question that changes the attributes of an object that exists through an association.
- I've tried using the Object.update method although I get an error that says:

  private method `update' called for #

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what did you expect? what did you get?

Comment: I expected to have the attributes for that user change in the database when I entered the console and queried them. 

Instead, the attributes for that user didn't change when I queried the database directly from console.

Comment: what was in your params?

Comment: "user"=>{"target_bf_pct"=>"0.16",
 "activity_factor"=>"1.75"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around with in the console I've found out that even if I change the attributes manually the attributes don't 'stick' after I exit the console.

So I'll enter console, change the users attributes, test them, and they'll be changed. If I exist and re-enter, THEN test them, they'll have reverted back to their default values.

This leads me to believe that the 'after_initialize' method within the user model which sets its default values is running after each save. I though that it would only run after the object had been saved for the first time alone but now I know it run each time it is saved.

```
after_initialize :default_values 

def default_values
  self.goal = "Cut"
  self.measurement = "US"
  self.bmr_formula = "katch"
  self.fat_factor = 0.655
  self.protein_factor = 1.25 
  self.deficit_pct = 0.10
  self.target_bf_pct = 0.10
  self.activity_factor = 1.3
end
```

Once I remove all these values and the after_initialize method, it saves permanently.

Answer (score 4):

Try the code :-

```
def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:success] = "Your settings have been saved!"
        render new_status_update_path
    else
        p 111111111111
        p  current_user.errors.inspect
    end
end
```

after check your log for any errors.exist for that active record

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you don't have any validation errors. You can check them using:

```
active_record_model.errors
```

In your case, it would be

```
current_user.errors
```

Also, you should print the return value from `update_attributes` to see if it's `true` or `false`. If you get `false`, the save was cancelled. This was most likely caused by validation errors or a callback returning `false`.

Comment: The error message prints #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fd944dac710>

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:success] = "Your settings have been saved!"
        render new_status_update_path
    else
        some_error_handling_code
    end
end
```

Would not display success when the save fails.  As a general rule, you should check whether a save, or any other back end operation, fails, before reporting success to the end user.

Comment: It's flashing the success message even though the attributes aren't being saved. My guess is that it's got something to do with the user model's "after_initialize" method that sets some default values for the model.

Comment: That would make sense.  Glad I was able to help.  Since you're using this code now, could you accept my answer?

Comment: I'd like to although it wouldn't be fair to the first answer that came in which helped a lot as well. Besides, I found the real answer as a result of both of your guidance so yea. I did upvote both of you though :) Thanks again.